# ¿Cómo ejecutar función JavaScript al mostrar vista parcial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un botón en mi página que al hacer click sobre él, se muestra una página parcial,
...Ahora necesito que cuando esta página parcial se muestre o renderize sobre la principal...se ejecute una función JavaScript

En la página principal tengo este código:

```
<button data-url="@Url.Action("Precio", "Conexiones", new { Area = "" })"> Precio Conexion </button>
```

En mi controlador:

```
 public ActionResult Precio()
 {
   return PartialView("_PrecioConexion");
 }
```

En la vista parcial:

HTML:

```
<table id="tablaListaPrecios" class="display compact dt-center" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ListaPrecios)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Status)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 @section scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#tablaListaPrecios').DataTable({
            language: {
                   url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
            ajax: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("ListaPrecios", "Precios")",
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        JsBase.Error("Existe un error al realizar la solicitud. StatusCode:" + jqXHR.status);
                    }
            },
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                fixedColumns: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        targets: 1, width: "3%",
                        className: "dt-body-center", render: function (data, type, row)
                        { return '<div><input type="checkbox"  onClick="AddListaPrecio(' + "'" + row.CveLista + "'" + ')" ></div>'; } },

                     { data: "@Html.IdFor(x=>x.CveLista)", width: "5%", className: "dt-body-center"  },
                     { data: "@Html.IdFor(x=>x.ListaPrecios)", width: "20%" },
                     { data: "@Html.IdFor(x=>x.Status)", width: "5%", className: "dt-body-center" },
                ]
          });

        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al llamar el PartialView estas declarando la función mas no ejecutándola, entonces debería quedar algo asi:

```
function Mi_Funcion_A_Ejecutar(){

  // AQUÍ MI CODIGO JS

}
Mi_Funcion_A_Ejecutar(); // Aqui estoy ejecutando
```

Ahora si lo traes desde Ajax, recomiendo separar tu código JS en un archivo y declararla de esta manera

```
var partialView = function Mi_Funcion_A_Ejecutar(){
  var init = function(){
    //Script de codigo que se hara al cargar
  }
  // AQUÍ MI CODIGO JS
  return { init : init }
}();
```

En tu Ajax estaria asi:

```
$.get("/Conexiones/Precio").then(success => {
  $("#div").html(success);
  partialView.init()
});
```

Psdt: Tu PartialView deberia estar referenciado al archivo JS

Espero haberte ayudado.